# Is there a way to list all the items of a list in a webpart ,so that one or two column value can be updated for multiple list items?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SP 2013 online. And I do not have the option of using server side coding

Comment: DataSheet View is an option. Opening the View in Access is an option. Or using Client Side Rendering you can enhance any View. Do you understand the basics of JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can create any type of view of your list you'd like to see, this includes only the columns you want and filtered as you'd like. From there, it is just a click away to go into quick edit mode to edit whatever you'd like.

Comment: Eric ! Thanks for the answer . I had missed some details in the question. I am thinking of a webpart which will have a column against each row to display edit link . A pop up appears and after fields are edited, edited values get filled in item columns and save button updates all of the updated ones. Going the route of popup is to enforce user selects the correct ID values ( I am trying to reference list ID with other list ID's if they choose to ). So the value selected aginst a column in popup will be itself or other list ID's